# Google-map - based on ID

Tags: javascript, google-maps

While implementing google maps - if the ID of the div is 'map' the marker gets displayed, if it is something else, it does not.

https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

function

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

here if you change the id of the div and even at document.getElementByid from map to anything else it will not work.

is it to be change elsewhere also?

Changed the code to two maps

```js
function myMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.12),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}






      function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

        var mape = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: mape,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
```

```html
<h3>Using Google Maps API</h3>
<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCNHfIW2WzOTpRnHXHstqwVWJg9NVDOQgg&callback=myMap"></script>

  <h3>Using Google Maps API - markers</h3>
<div id="map2"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=AIzaSyB-aH4ym18aYYe86IiamWV88X-JrVhFLt8&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the API key, bro

Comment: You are including the API twice, don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your **API KEY** Try another API KEY.

```js
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title:'hello word',
  });
  
  var myLatLng2 = {lat: -25.363, lng: 15.044};

  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map3'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: myLatLng2
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng2,
    map: map2,
    title:'hello word',
  });
}
```

```css
#map2, #map3{
height:200px;
width:500px;
margin-bottom:50px;

border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="map2"></div>


<div id="map3"></div>

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=AIzaSyB-aH4ym18aYYe86IiamWV88X-JrVhFLt8&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: but if you use Google Maps API multiple times only the first one gets displayed

Comment: I have added the code with two maps - it says multiple maps cant be used

Comment: Also view the snippet again with one key i am showing two maps.

Comment: Don't add multiple time G JS LIB

Comment: So I have to use single function and give different var to different map. Thanks a lot. This explanation and example makes more sense. Thanks again :)